# Alexa Skills Kit: Can't get AMAZON.NUMBER, AMAZON.DATE to work

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

This should be simple and straightforward, but I am having a hard time getting it to work. So:

**Using AMAZON.LITERAL for a number like below works fine:**

*IntentSchema:*

```
{
     "intent": "Group_Size",
     "slots":[
        {
          "name": "GroupSize",
          "type": "AMAZON.LITERAL"
        }
      ]
  }
```

*Sample Utterance:*

```
Group_Size {forty thousand|GroupSize}
```

**BUT** when I change the slot type to `AMAZON.NUMBER` (which is what it should be) and utter 'forty thousand' or 'three nine six seven four' it stops working. The returned intent is one that is intended for Help and not `Group_Size` anymore (in other words, an irrelevant/incorrect intent is returned).

Same issue when I use `AMAZON.DATE` for one of my other intents.

I am fairly new to A-S-K, so is there anything special I need to do to get these predefined types to work? I went through the documentation and some code samples, but didn't find any gotchas. Any pointers please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked when I passed `NUMBER` instead of `AMAZON.NUMBER`.

Comment: How did you find out about NUMBER vs AMAZON.NUMBER? Is this documented anywhere?